# Twitter API duplicated urls in extended_entities

Tags: api, twitter

I figured out twitter api responses wrong informatino about media. While parsing tweets, I found that for some tweets, although the tweet contains two other images, the json data contains two SAME image links in `extended_entities`. Since the problematic tweet is a protected tweet, I brought another example of `extended_entities` error.

The below is the part of json data of https://twitter.com/BigBlueDoge/status/575351257239527425.

```
"media": [
    {
        // omitted
        "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/B_wO62IW8AADcj6.jpg",
        "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B_wO62IW8AADcj6.jpg",
        // omitted
    },
    {
        // omitted
        "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/B_wO62OXEAAVrNp.jpg",
        "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B_wO62OXEAAVrNp.jpg",
        // omitted
    }
]
```

Has anyone got answer for this error?

Comment: I suggest you take this directly to Twitter since they'll be able to look at the protected tweet themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure what the error is in your example though: those are the two different images that appear in that tweet, and look correct to me?

Comment: @Rup No difference, because the example I brought also has the problem. The example is from the forum in Twitter Dev Forum

Comment: @Rup You go through the link, then you see two different images in a tweet. Yet, twitter api returns two identical image links.

Comment: Yes, the tweet has a blue dog, and the first two URLs you've posted above show a blue dog ([http](http://pbs.twimg.com/media/B_wO62IW8AADcj6.jpg), [https](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B_wO62IW8AADcj6.jpg)) and a green dog, and the second two URLs you've posted above show a green dog ([http](http://pbs.twimg.com/media/B_wO62OXEAAVrNp.jpg), [https](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B_wO62OXEAAVrNp.jpg)). Yes each image has two different URLs, but one has protocol http and one protocol https. I'd guess these are legacies from a time when Twitter hosted HTTPS content on a different domain.

Comment: Is that the issue you're reporting: that media_url and media_url_https return the same image? I can't find 'BlueDogDoge' in the [Twitter Dev Forum](https://twittercommunity.com/search?q=BlueDogDoge).

Comment: @Rup Oh I've got the wrong example. You're right. I see no problem in the example. I was reporting issue that two `media_url`s in each element under `media` were identical. There are some tweets that are actually identical. But the example I posted indeed has different image links. I'll find the relevant example and post again.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was solved by myself... When retrieving status, add a parameter `tweet_mode=extended` to avoid the problem above.